# Statement trigger in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm studying for a DBMS exam and I was trying to do some triggers. No problem with "standard" row triggers but the problem came up with a statement trigger.

The exercise is to create a trigger that raise an exception if the sum of the values of a certain column is updated below a minimum value (30).

So the table is something like:

```
ID | VALUE
----------
 1 |  23
 2 |  11
 3 |  14
```

and the update will do something like

```
UPDATE TABLE SET VALUE = VALUE - 10
```

and this should throw an exception because the sum before is 48 and  after the update would be 18.

I've tried with a row trigger but doing the select on the same table will throw a "mutating table" warning, so looking for this I came up that this should due to a poor trigger design.

Probably I should implement a statement trigger but seems that I'm not able to access the new_table or the old_table, and I don't know how to write them. That's lame because they seems quite simple but I couldn't find anything useful or any example.

Any help?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

and also the new_table/old_table references seems to exist in [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.3.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj43125.html#rrefsqlj43125__sqlj54276)..

Comment: Your link points to the manual of `JavaDB` (which is a re-branded Apache Derby database). That has nothing to do with the Oracle DBMS. The real Oracle DBMS manual can be found here: http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/docindex

Comment: Ups, I thought that was Oracle due to the hosting address. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_xyz
AFTER UPDATE ON tableX
DECLARE
  v_sum number;
BEGIN

  SELECT SUM(VALUE) into v_sum
  FROM tableX;

  IF v_sum < 30 THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001,"ERROR MESSAGE");
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried more or less something like this, without the referencing part I think. I'm going to check it tomorrow morning and let you know! Thanks

Comment: I updated the answer. Statement triggers don't support the referencing clause. So i put it as `AFTER UPDATE` so maybe the new data could be acquired with a normal select on the table. Try it and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Oracle syntax but I believe `new_table` is the same as `INSERTED` in SQL Server; if so something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TableName_U
BEFORE UPDATE
IF (SELECT SUM(VALUE) FROM new_table) < 30 THEN
    BEGIN
        raise error syntax
        abort update syntax
    END
```